# Logic App xpath - how can I get the value without the json syntax?

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps

I execute an xpath function in my Logic App to set the value of a variable.
The result is a guid and the variable is formatted as [""].
I want to use this variable in a body message sent to an http endpoint and when I use the variable content, it sent the [""] but I need just to send the .
I'm a bit lost here because I don't know how to extract only the Json value of this variable...
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The result of the xpath function is a json array of XML nodes matching your xpath expression. If you are only expecting a single node, you can use the `@first` function to reference it

`"@first(xpath(...))"`

Answer (score 0):

when you need only one value without any filters this will work.
document_url: is the XML tag, here the path to the node is not required.

```
xpath(xml(Body()),'//document_url/text()') ------- returns all the values
xpath(xml(Body()),'//document_url/text()')[0] ------ returns only the first value
```